# Want a regex which matches > char not containing in any tag

Tags: php, regex, tags

I want a regex which matches '>' char in the text such that it should not match `>` in the tags

For example -

```
"<span>some >text< again some<some tag></some tag>vfs>vf</span>"
```

Should match - `<span>some >text< again some<some tag></some tag>vfs>vf</span>`
..............................................|..............................................................|

Where the `|` indicates the `>` to be matched.

For reference I have prepared a regex which does the same thing for `<`

Here is my regex - `"/(?!<[^<>]*>)**<**/"` (here '<' is just in bold to show here)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"i have prepared a regex which do same thing for <"_ - Well, if you have a regex that matches `<`, why not just change that to match `>` instead?

Comment: no it is not simply satisfying for > by using same regex with this modification. that's why requested for any other idea/regex

Comment: The `'~</?[A-Za-z_][^<>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|<~'` will help to some extent with some assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your requirements are simple - don't include quoted or escaped angle brackets, nor nested angle bracket pairs, the problem of finding a STARTING unmatched bracket is the first position of a string starting with an open bracket, containing no internal brackets, and ending with either another open bracket or the end of the string.

In regex speak, that would be:

```
/(<)[^<>]*(?:$|<)/
```

Because you want to capture all of them, and will be using preg_match_all, you need to add in look ahead to catch the overlapping matches:

```
/(?=(<)[^<>]*(?:$|<))/
```

Similarly, the unmatched right bracket problem simplifies to the last character of a string starting with either the beginning of a string or a close bracket, and ending with the close bracket, with no bracket in between.  Adding in look ahead, you get:

```
/(?=(?:^|>)[^<>]*(>))/
```

I added a couple of extra brackets to your test strings to make sure we catch the end and overlapping cases, and a replacement example:

```
<?php
// Left angle brackets
$x = "<span>some >text< again<< some<some tag><</some tag>vfs>vf</span><<";
$y = preg_match_all('/(?=(<)[^<>]*(?:$|<))/', $x, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
echo "Test: '{$x}'\n";
echo "Repl: '" . locate_replace($x, $match[1], '\<') . "'\n";
echo "There are {$y} extra left angle brackets at character positions:\n";
echo "  " . implode(", ", array_column($match[1], 1)) . "\n\n";

// Right angle brackets

$x = "abc><span>some >text< again some<some tag></some tag>vfs>>vf</span>";
$y = preg_match_all('/(?=(?:^|>)[^<>]*(>))/', $x, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
echo "Test: '{$x}'\n";
echo "Repl: '" . locate_replace($x, $match[1], '\>') . "'\n";
echo "There are {$y} extra right angle brackets at character positions:\n";
echo "  " . implode(", ", array_column($match[1], 1)) . "\n";

function locate_replace($x, $match_oc, $repl) {
    while ($mt = array_pop($match_oc)) {
        $sloc = $mt[1];
        $eloc = $sloc + strlen($mt[0]);
        $x = substr($x, 0, $sloc) . $repl . substr($x, $eloc);
    }
    return $x;
}
?>
```

And this produces:

```
Test: '<span>some >text< again<< some<some tag><</some tag>vfs>vf</span><<'
Repl: '<span>some >text\< again\<\< some<some tag>\<</some tag>vfs>vf</span>\<\<'
There are 6 extra left angle brackets at character positions:
  16, 23, 24, 40, 65, 66

Test: 'abc><span>some >text< again some<some tag></some tag>vfs>>vf</span>'
Repl: 'abc\><span>some \>text< again some<some tag></some tag>vfs\>\>vf</span>'
There are 4 extra right angle brackets at character positions:
  3, 15, 56, 57
```

Comment: Hi @wordragon, i don't want a word i just want the > chars from those positions, just like did in "/(?!<[^<>]*>)</"  to get < char.. but thanks for your response :)

Comment: I meant not the first position all those occurrences present in the text. when i checked above pattern then it is not returning like '<span>some >text>< again some<some tag></some tag>vfs>vf</span>'

Comment: Actually, it does give you what you asked for - $match[1][0] tells you the match is a ">" at position 11 and $match[1][1] tells you the second match is a ">" at position 52.  You can ignore the words in $match[0] - they are just the strings used to find your matches.

Comment: ok.. can you see and try this  https://regex101.com/r/7F2ySz/3 (just put some chars in text so timeout won't happen).. so in the same way i want regex for >

Comment: I added look ahead (realized I was missing overlapping cases), improved examples to include the end cases.  I also interpreted the $match array properly.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @wordragon, can you tell me how how can i tell preg_replace to replace $1 instead of $0 ? i am using the 2nd case your in which i want to escape match[1], so for that i am using preg_replace and i just want to replace $1 to \$1 in the given value

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want to do.  If you are trying to autocorrect unmatched brackets, remember that the second close bracket (or first open bracket) may be the correct one.  however, if I wanted to, for example, delete the offending characters, I'd probably just loop through the result (array_column($match[1], 1)) in reverse order and remove that character.  At some point, I find it better to burn a few extra ergs and microseconds than search for the perfect one-liner:-)

Comment: basically i want exact match of '>' and with your pattern it is there in matches[1], but i am using preg_replace and in preg_replace it matches[0] means full match and replaces the with replacement string., so i am doing in < pattern (regex101.com/r/7F2ySz/3 ) so is it possible do form pattern which directly matches '>'  ??

Comment: actually in the replacement i'll put \< - means escaping those < char

Comment: I put in an example of using the array for replacement - not sure its very elegant, but it works.  Again, a caution that the one you are escaping may not be the correct one.

Comment: thanks for your work, but if it needs to do with php code,  then i can do that very easily, BUT  in my software it uses preg_replace() and in that one xml file where we have put all search pattern and replace strings, so according to that i want a pattern which exactly matches '<' so that i can replace it (escape it). and for your pattern preg_replace strictly replace matche0 means full match, that's the limitation.. i can't help it, 
so please if it is possible to you, can you please give me the pattern which exactly matches < , it will very great :)