# Require a regex directly matches > excluding valid html tags

Tags: php, regex, pcre

in my last question 
[Want a regex which matches > char not containing in any tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49504955/want-a-regex-which-matches-char-not-containing-in-any-tag)
i got the answer but it is not directly matching to >

one of the valid answer from last question is `'/(?=(?:^|>)[^<>]*(>))/'` which matches `>` excluding from valid html tags 
test string is `'abc><span>some >text< again some<some tag></some tag>vfs>>vf</span>'`

Please help me to get the regex which directly matches `>`, not any matches[] array

Comment: Don't use regex for this. Get familiar with DOM parsers, iteration, and eventually recursion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
`>|(<.*?>|.)(*SKIP)(*F)`